# MySQL Select row from a select

Tags: mysql, database

I really don't know how to ask this question
But I wanna select a row from a select command
So... I did a command that sorts every xp value from low to high and gives it a rank

```
SELECT id, xp, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM xp p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r ORDER BY xp DESC;
```

If I have id value can I check the row it's in? and then find the rank value?
Cause I mean the value is in a select is there even a way to select from a select
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a subquery, so the DB can first calculate the rank and afterwards you can select it

```
select rank
from
(
    SELECT id, xp, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
    FROM xp
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
    ORDER BY xp DESC
) tmp
where id = 123
```